# Function of .pop() on an empty stack

Tags: c++, stack, std

I'm working on some code for an extra credit project and came across something peculiar that I wanted to see if someone could explain for a better understanding. I have a for loop that populates a std::stack and then another that pops the stack for the same amount of time it's populated. I was wondering what would happen if I attempted to pop() when the stack itself is empty already.

Comment: It's UB: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back

Comment: You have to check first to avoid the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the default `std::stack` container of `std::deque`, calling `pop()` on an empty stack would invoke **undefined behavior**.

"undefined behavior" means that your program's behavior can no longer be relied upon in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a documentation trail to follow. You are asking about the behavior of `std::stack::pop()` in a certain situation. So start with the documentation for that function.

**[`std::stack<T,Container>::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop)**

> Effectively calls `c.pop_back()`

It is not explicitly clear what is meant by `c`, but further down the page is a mention of `Container::pop_back`, so it is reasonable to infer that that is the next thing to look up. (Note that `Container` is the second template parameter.) You might have a difficulty here if you did not specify a second template parameter for your `stack`. In that case, back up to the documentation for `std::stack` to see what the default is.

**[`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)**

> By default, if no container class is specified for a particular stack class instantiation, the standard container `std::deque` is used.

Aha! So we need to look up the `pop_back()` member of `std::deque`.

**[`std::deque<T,Allocator>::pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back)**

> Calling `pop_back` on an empty container results in undefined behavior.

There's your answer: undefined behavior. Now you might be asking yourself [what is undefined behavior in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) In brief, undefined behavior allows your program's behavior to be whatever is convenient for the compiler. Technically, it allows any behavior whatsoever, but in practice, compilers just do whatever is convenient.